# Achieving automatic re-sizing/positioning of elements based on screen resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css, resolution

I have been looking at http://www.nytimes.com/chrome and wondering how I can achieve a similar functionality to theirs. More specifically, notice that when you re-size your browser window, the amount of stories and their dimensions change dynamically.

In my case, I have a fluid-width <div> with an unordered list inside and I would like to dynamically adjust number of elements being displayed (<li>) based on the browser window dimensions.

Is there a Javascript library that can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use these three articles as references for this type of thing:

- [Responsive Web Design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/)
- [Fluid Images](http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images)
- [Fluid Grids](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/)

The two main techniques for really fluid websites are:

1. Different themes depending on the size of the browser (this can be implemented with CSS meda queries, JavaScript, etc.)
2. Each of those themes are defined with percentages/ems, **not** pixels. (This goes for everything in the theme: text, boxes, images, *everything*.)

Ethan Marcotte, the guy who wrote all those articles, has an [example site](http://www.alistapart.com/d/responsive-web-design/ex/ex-site-larger.html) employing these ideas.

Answer (score 1):

It's called [responsive design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/). There also css frameworks that supports this type of design like [Less Framework 3](http://lessframework.com/) or [Flaw{LESS} CSS Framework](http://wizzart.at/development/flawless-css-framework/).

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to check out this plugin: [Smart Columns](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/smart-columns-w-css-jquery/). I have used it and it is excellent for this type of layout.